# Gibt es eine Präposition für die Verwendung mit "gewidmet"?

Tags: preposition

In einem Buch ist eine Widmung folgendermaßen enthalten:

> Gewidmet für Herrn A und Frau B, Leitern des ...

Mein Sprachempfinden sagt mir, dass "für" hier falsch ist. Es müsste meiner Meinung nach heißen:

> Gewidmet Herrn A und Frau B, ...

ohne "für"

Jetzt meine Frage: Gibt es eine gültige Präposition, die man mit "gewidmet" verwenden kann? Wenn ja, welche? Oder ist mein Gefühl richtig?

Das Buch ist eine Übersetzung aus dem Englischen. Dort gibt es ja "dedicated to".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Jmdm. (Dat.) etw. (Akk.)* widmen](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=widmen) wird wie z. B. auch "schenken" nicht mit einer Präposition benutzt. Es muss deshalb heißen:

> Gewidmet Frau A und Herrn B.
>   Meinen Eltern gewidmet.
>   Er widmete seine Dissertation seinen Eltern.

Comment: Danke für die Bestätigung meines Gefühls!