# I would like to give a book to a German friend as a gift, what is an appropriate dedication sentence?

Tags: idiom, sentence-structure, formality

I would like to give a book of classical literature of my country, Iran, to a German friend who is a professor of mathematics and philosophy at Berlin university.

I want to write a good memorial sentence beside my sign on the first page in German but I'm not sure if a direct translation of a usual English dedication sentence is an appropriate sentence in German as well.

What are good candidates for book dedication sentences in German language?

Comment: I am new in this forum. Please help me with editing the current tags to better ones.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for a well-written, nicely formatted question! As it stands, this question is fairly broad, perhaps you could narrow it down to a few suggestions? It's hard to answer when we don't know *what you want to say*. And, while I very much applaud your intention to write in German (the recipient being German, I presume?), writing the inscription in English would be perfectly acceptable if you feel more comfortable doing so. A scientific professional should be fluent in English. But don't let this keep you from writing in German!

Comment: That the question would be slightly better if you at least would state what you want to say her/him. Concerning the use of German, don't copy a phrase written here: it would be transparent to a native speaker that you didn't write it.

Answer (score 6):

There is not a fixed rule or recommendation what you write when signing a book you want to give away as a present. Just be careful with terms you may find when searching for the German term "[Widmung](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20110/gibt-es-eine-pr%C3%A4position-f%C3%BCr-die-verwendung-mit-gewidmet)" (dedication) as this can be done by the author only.

Having said that, it is possible to write anything warm and joyful, probably you know better than us what meets your relationship to your friend.

If I was the recipient I'd probably love to see a quote of a Persian proverb you liked or that describes your relationship to your friend. You could even write in Farsi with a German translation added to make it more personal. It could also be a quote from the book.

Example:

> یک معلم خوب باعث می شود مخاطبان را ببینید با گوش خو
>   <sup>Persisches Sprichwort</sup>
>   Bei einem guten Redner fangen die Zuhörer an, mit den Ohren zu sehen.

You sure will quote the Farsi original much better than my Google translate attempt does.

After that you then just put a small greeting as space is limited, e.g.

> Mit Grüßen aus dem Iran Ihr/Dein *(signature)*

Comment: This is a nice sentence. I suggest to replace "Redner" by "Erzähler". The system don't allow me to edit the typo "Persiches". Correct is: "Persisches".

Comment: @rkhb: it's just an example ... 'Redner' is the appropriate term for the German version of this proverb (see Google) and it is somehwat closer to what a professor does.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of formulations are possible, eg

Als Zeichen meiner Wertschätzung eines lieben/teuren Freundes/ eines hervorragenden Lehrers.

Comment: +1, ich kann nicht verstehen, wieso diese Antwort negativ bewertet worden ist. Denjenigen, die das gemacht haben: bitte zumiendest erklären, wieso diese Antwort falsch sein soll.

Comment: @c.p.: Ich habe nicht abgewertet, aber ich selbst wäre beleidigt, wenn jemand ein gutes Buch damit besudelt. Das ist förmlich, unpersönlich und letztlich abwertend. Auf einer separaten Karte wäre es eventuell noch hinnehmbar.

Comment: @rkhb - Ich nehme an, du würdest einem Hochschulprofessor schreiben Hallo, Kumpel, ich mag dich.

Comment: @rogermue: Ich hätte bei einem Hochschulprofessor überhaupt Bedenken, irgend etwas in ein Buch zu kritzeln.

Comment: Komische Auffassung hast du Über Geschenke. Der Fragesteller hat offensichtlich eine andere Meinung.